# Regex failing in max length

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, c#-4.0

I want regex which will allow following format

```
  1234567-8
  123456B
```

Now here if user enter second pattern then he should be lock to enter maximum 7 characters so

```
 1234568B
  123456V1
this becomes invalid
```

I have tried

```
[0-9]{7}-[0-9]|[[0-9]{6}[A-z]{1}]{7,7}
```

but this fails

Comment: Maybe [`^([0-9]{7}-[0-9]|[0-9]{6}[A-Za-z])$`](https://regex101.com/r/iJ8bU3/2). There is at least one character class too much and the `A-z` is a typo, right? Placing a quantifier `{1}` into a character class makes it a simple symbol combination.

Answer (score 0):

**For the sample input you provided**, you may use [`^([0-9]{7}-[0-9]|[0-9]{6}[A-Za-z])$`](https://regex101.com/r/iJ8bU3/2).

A bit more contracted version: [`^[0-9]{6}(?:[0-9]-[0-9]|[A-Za-z])$`](https://regex101.com/r/iJ8bU3/3).

Note that `1234567-8` has 7 digits and a hyphen followed with a digit, so the whole string length cannot be limited to just 7 characters all in all.

In .NET and almost all other regex flavors `[A-z]` is a mistake, as it can match more than just letters.

Placing a quantifier `{1}` into a character class makes it a simple symbol combination, so `[{1}]` matches either `{` or `1` or `}`.

The `{7,7}` (=`{7}`) will not limit the whole string length to 7, as you do not have *anchors* (`^` and `$`)  around the expression and you "ruined" the preceding quantifiers by putting them into a character class.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you need:

```
^(\d{7}-\d|\d{6}[A-Z])$
```

7 digits, dash, digit OR 6 digits, 1 large latin letter.

Answer (score 0):

^\d{6}(?:\d-\d|[A-Z])$

It can satisfy well with 2 your above formats

1234567-8

123456B